# Вместо двух картинок на сайте отображается надпись Warning : Illegal string offset 'id' in

Tags: php

Картинки должны подтягиваться автоматически, но с недавних пор вместо картинки надпись Warning : Illegal string offset 'id' in {адрес папки на сервере} main.tpl.php on line 86, сам код файла прилагаю ниже. В чем может быть проблема ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru" >

<head>
{include file='head.tpl'}
{include file='images.tpl'}
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    {include file='header.tpl'}
    <div id="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="whold">
                <div class="main-ad" id="agilego">
                        {*
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="/img/img012.jpg" alt="image description"  width="1179" height="218" />
                        <strong>Ведомый качеством</strong>
                    </a>
                    <script language="javascript">
                        AC_FL_RunContent(
                            'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab',
                            'width', '995',
                            'height', '249',
                            'src', '/flash/Animatie1.4.swf',
                            'quality', 'high',
                            'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
                            'align', 'middle',
                            'play', 'true',
                            'loop', 'true',
                            'scale', 'showall',
                            'wmode', 'opaque',
                            'devicefont', 'false',
                            'id', 'banners_3',
                            'bgcolor', '#ffffff',
                            'name', 'banners_3',
                            'menu', 'true',
                            'allowFullScreen', 'false',
                            'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
                            'movie', '/flash/Animatie1.4.swf',
                            'salign', ''
                            ); //end banner code
                    </script>*}
                </div>
                <div class="three-col">
                    <div class="aside1">
                        <div class="holder">
                            {$content}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="aside2">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <h2>Новости</h2>
                            <ul class="news-list">
                                {foreach name=news_index item=item from=$news_index}
                                    <li>
                                        <span>{$item.data.0} {$item.data.1} {$item.data.2}</span>
                                        <p><a href="/news/view/{$item.id}/">{$item.title}</a></p>
                                    </li>
                                {/foreach}
                            </ul>
```

### Запасные части

```
                                {$index1}
                            </div>
                            <h7><b>Акции</b></h7><br><br>
                            <div class="action-hold">
                                <div class="frame">
                                    {foreach name=news_index item=item from=$action_index}
                                    <div class="abox">
                                        <a href="/actions/view/{$item.id}/">
                                            <span style="Line-height:16px">
                                                {if $item.file.id != ''}<img src="/img/actions/{$item.file}" width="136" alt="" />{/if}
                                                <strong>{$item.title}</strong>
                                            </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    {/foreach}
```

```
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    {$indexseo}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {include file='footer.tpl'}
</div>
```

Comment: вероятно, что в $action_index[item] нету файла

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему

Comment: попробуйте там где у вас  {if $item.file.id != ''} поставить
  {if isset($item.file) && $item.file.id != ''}

Comment: не помогает, точно такая же ошибка(

Comment: Что у вас на 86 строке? в main.tpl.php

Comment: Если правильно понимаю то <strong>{$item.title}</strong>

Comment: Вроде да, ошибка связана с item.file.id. Попробуйте заменить  {if $item.file.id != ''} на {if isset($item.file.id)}